# Sequence $\{x_n\}$ that doesn't diverge to $\infty$, but $\{1/x_n\}$ converges to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series

Give an example of a sequence ${x_n}$, with each $x_n$ nonzero, such
that ${1/x_n}$ converges to 0 but $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ does not diverge to $\infty$.

I can't think of any examples.

Comment: $+\infty$ or $-\infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many sequence which keep oscillating with magnitude becoming arbitrarily large. For instance, $x_n = (-2)^n$.

Answer (score 4):

$1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,7,-8,9,-10,\dots$

Comment: @user3491648 Given the user's question, it is highly unlikely that he knows about one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$. Do not boast about knowing more, when the question is clear from the context.

Comment: anyway, i'm deleting my comments.

Comment: lol I think I've missed what's happening here...

Answer (score 1):

$$-1, -2, -3, -4 \dotsc \longrightarrow -\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

You can construct an example of such a sequence like this. Take two
sequences one tends to $+\infty $ and the other to $-\infty .$ The inverses
of each of them converges to $0.$ Now, construct a third sequence such that
its terms of odd ranks are those of the first sequence, and its terms of the
even ranks are those of the second. This third sequence do not converges at
all because it has two sequences with different limits. However, the
sequence of terms inverted converges to $0.$ Concrete example. Let $x_{n}=n$
and $y_{n}=-n$ and the third one $(u_{n})$ is defined such that $%
u_{2k+1}=x_{k}=k$ and $u_{2k}=y_{k}=-k$ for any $k\geq 1$.